# What is \directlua0{} vs \directlua{}

Tags: luatex, directlua

The title is the question. According to the LuaTeX manual, command `\directlua{code}` may have a 16-bit number between the command and the code, and I have seen `\directlua0{code}` here and there. But I did not see any explanation of what that number does.

I do not have a code issue. Just asking for info.

Comment: they are separate lua chunks basically acting like 16 different internal files

Comment: Got it. I will leave the question posted, in case anyone else wants to know.

Comment: 2^16 not 16 possible chunks, sorry

Comment: Maybe an example which illustrates this feature should be useful. The LuaTeX manual isn't clear in this matter.

Comment: @wipet I was wondering about that, I have some examples but not so useful, do you have a good example, feel free to post one if you do

Comment: Sorry, I never needed this feature, IMHO it is irrelevant feature. If somebody knows an example where a numbered chunk of directlua is explicitly needed then it will be usable. directlua of directlua works without the need to specify a chunk with different number.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It might be that the developer put that, "in case it is ever needed." I have done things like that, for my own use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a debugging feature which can be used if you have many `\directlua` calls to make it easier to figure out where some error is coming from. The ID is used to lookup a name which is then used as a name for the function which appears e.g. in stack traces.

Take for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
  error'Oh no, this failed.'
}
\stop
```

This fails with the message

> ```
> [\directlua]:1: Oh no, this failed.
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'error'
>   [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
> ```

Here the source is given as `[\directlua]:1:` which might not be very helpful if you have many `\directlua` calls in your document.

Instead, you can assign a name to a Lua segment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{ lua.setluaname(1, "=[foobar]") }
\directlua1{
  error'Oh no, this failed.'
}
\stop
```

Now you get the error

> ```
> [foobar]:1: Oh no, this failed.
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'error'
>   [foobar]:1: in main chunk.
> ```

so if instead of `foobar` you have a more descriptive string (e.g. the package name containing the `\directlua` call) then you have an easier time figuring out what triggered the problem.
Of course this requires you to use a unique number, in LaTeX you can allocate one with `\newluachunkname`.

If you only want to use a name in a few places a more direct way to get the same effect is to use the `name` keyword to specify the name inline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua name {=[foobar]} {
  error'Oh no, this failed.'
}
\stop
```

This will again produce:

> ```
> [foobar]:1: Oh no, this failed.
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'error'
>   [foobar]:1: in main chunk.
> ```

For `\directlua` this is usually not that useful since direct errors will also show the TeX line number which helps placing the call, but it can still be useful if you define functions and pass them around. For `\latelua` it tends to be a bit more helpful since there the line numbers provided by TeX are much less helpful.

Finally, the `\directlua0` you see in some packages is useless. Theoretically it uses the registered name with ID 0 for this `\directlua` call, but since calls using this are all over the place and noone ever sets `lua.setluaname(0, '...')` this doesn't make a difference. Using a number which does not have a name assigned is the same as not specifying a number in the first place.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. As someone who never, ever makes an error, I did not imagine that there was such a thing as "debugging." :-)

Comment: @rallg We've found the coding unicorn. :-)